# PHP ARGB to Alpha-Hex and Alpha-Hex to ARGB

Tags: php, rgba

I got the following color `-16777216` and I want to convert it to a alpha-hex code like this `00FFBBCC` in PHP. I also want to be able to do the reverse. I really don't know where to start and my friend Google has no answer for me.

Any one can help please ?

Thank you.

Comment: Hex contains 6 chars only

Comment: @Mr.Alien Yes, I know. However, I wanted to say Hex with the alpha in front. It's a lengths of 8 hex code.

Comment: Didn't knew that, thanks :) hex seems like a bad word, should be like octa ;)

Comment: No. It's a hex color like 000000 with 2 extras 8 bits in front of the chain that define the alpha. It's called RGBA

Comment: Ya I got that, but 6 characters and hex looks bad, 8 should be with octa, anyways thanks for the explanation :)

Comment: Why is your color negative? Or is this some sort of signed 25 bit number? (25 bit = wtf?)

Comment: I always thought it was named hex colors from "hexadecimals", numbers with base 16 (0-9A-F), and not because it has six digits. If that is the case, no reason to change the name just because of the added two digits for the alpha value ;)

Answer (score 1):

What about using dechex()?

```
echo dechex(-16777216);
```

It outputs ff000000

If you want uppercase letters, simply use strtoupper():

```
echo strtoupper(dechex(-16777216)); //FF000000
```

Edit: to do the reverse, use hexdec() instead of dechex()